# When I add google+ button to my website, how can I be aware that `access_token` expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-plus, access-token

Access tokens periodically expire and, when that happens, need to be refreshed. When an access token expires or at any other time, your application may be able to use a refresh token to obtain a new, valid access token. Server-side web applications, installed applications, and devices all obtain refresh tokens during the authorization process.

I take this information from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

How can I be aware that access_token expired ?

Comment: What kind of Google+ button are you thinking of?

Comment: Is there difference ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very common approach is to catch HTTP Errors for all API requests you make. If you run into a 401 error it means the access token is not valid any more and you can try to refresh it and repeat the original request. If the token refresh fails it most likely means that the user has revoked access for your app.

In pseudo code:

```
result = makeApiRequest();
if (result.status == 401) {
    refreshToken();
    result = makeApiRequest();
}
```

Some of the Google APIs client libraries (for example the one for Python) will take care of that for you automatically, but unfortunately not all of them.

Comment: It is not clear for me.
Now I use Javascript code to add Google+ Sign in button.
And in C# side, 

`string json =GetGoogleUserJSON(Request.QueryString["accessToken"]);
 GoogleUser guser=new GoogleUser();
 guser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleUser>(json);`

And now on localhost everything is good.
My project works normal.

Should I check access_token at that time ?

Comment: And If user has revoked, next time when he would like to sign in with Google+, My project will ask him for permissons and again Google will send access_token to my project. Am I wrong ?
May be I can not understand this issue.

Comment: No, as @Scarygami said, you can do the check when you actually try to use the token on the server. If you get an "unauthorized" response when you try to use it, you may need to refresh it at that time.

Comment: thanks @Prisoner.
In my projct I get user's data when they sign in with their facebook or google+. And then I copy those data to my User class. And I use this class as Session. 
I think that for my project I don't need to check access_token.

Comment: @Scarygami,
as Google.com , there are 15 error types.
Don't you know which all of them should check exactly ?

Comment: @Prisoner , as Google.com , there are 15 error types. Don't you know which all of them should check exactly ?

Comment: This sounds like an unrelated question that you should post separately with more details.